# Converting negative voltage to positive for PIC (ADC)

Tags: circuit-design, adc, pic

I have an unstable DC output voltage between 1.5 V and -1.5 V.  I want to program a PIC so that it shows me how the voltage changes between +1.5 V and -1.5 V. I am using the ADC pin of my PIC, but it has to be positive voltage.

What would be an elegant circuit design to do an overall offset of 1.5 V to have a voltage change between 0V and +3V? What would be a good way to realize that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have 3.3 V for your MCU available, how about a non-inverting summing amplifier and a 1.5 V offset? V1 represents your -1.5 to +1.5 V signal.

R1 and R2 sets the gain in the circuit. For a gain of 1, set R1=R2 and your summing resistors R5 and R6 to same value.

R3 and R4 is just a voltage divider to get 1.5 V. Values below are a bit lazy. Depending on your input impedance R5, you can go higher to bleed less current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKf8tE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Voted up, but OP might need some clarification for values of R1 and R2

Comment: @pm101 Good point. The duplicate seemed to answer it but I’ll add it here as well for user-friendliness.